# French equivalents of "my heart leaps"

Tags: anglais, allemand

> Es macht viel mehr Spaß, jederzeit dorthin fahren zu können, wohin es uns gefällt. Ach, die Reise ist schon was Feines – da **macht das Herz Sprünge**!

We were having a conversation in German, and here I was talking about how **our hearts leap** (with excitement/joy) at the thought of setting off on a journey.

I'm wondering how this idea is commonly expressed in French. The first phrasing, though not literally translated, that sprang to mind was:

> C’est tellement mieux de prendre la mer quand bon nous semble pour aller où bon nous semble. Tu sais, le voyage est une chose merveilleuse. On **se sent le cœur** si **léger** !

Answer (score 2):

*Avoir le cœur léger* does not convey the exact idea you are looking for. It is closer to being "light-hearted".

Avoir le cœur léger dans le ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A9ger)) :

> Être débarrassé de tout chagrin, de toute préoccupation; se sentir heureux.

For *macht das Herz Sprünge* I'd rather use something very similar involving the beating of the heart.

- mon cœur **saute de joie** (bondit de joie) à cette idée.

There's a typically French expression that could be used: *battre la chamade* ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chamade)) but it does not necessarily involve joy, only some sort of emotion ; it is very often used in an amorous context.

- J'ai le cœur qui bat la chamade.

Although I would not use it in any circumstance (and not in the context of your question), I feel you should be aware of the expression;

- j'ai le cœur qui fait boum/mon cœur fait boum.

It alludes to [Charles Treinet 1930's song](http://www.charles-trenet.net/chansons/boum.html). Not used very often but still you can encounter it occasionally.

Comment: I see. Close, but no cigar, then. Another phrasing I'd have said is: "*On a le cœur qui s'emballe*".

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Much better to my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Know that our French hearts also leap :) Be it out of fear or out of joy.

> sb's heart misses a beat

would translate to

> le cœur de qqn fait un bond
>
> J'ai entendu sa voix et mon cœur a fait un bond.

Also I thought you might enjoy this little [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtG17SgxF8s) (Mon cœur bondit de joie) :)

That said, I would have gone with something very literal

> ça fait bondir le cœur

But according to [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bondir), that means

> se dit pour exprimer l’extrême répugnance qu’on a pour un aliment ou pour quelque autre chose qui fait soulever l’estomac

Well, that's not exactly what we're trying to express...

Maybe then

> ça fait bondir le coeur de joie

That leaves no room for ambiguity :)

For something less literal, as it's often not so easy to translate a text word for word

> ça vous remplit/(literary:emplit) de joie

As a side note, there is this expression "mettre le baume au coeur" (also: ça réchauffe le coeur) but that's more like

> da wird einer warm ums Herz

Answer (score 1):

An expression that might be too literary here is *le cœur se dilate*.  This *dilatatio cordis* is a *Herzerweiterung*. It refers to immense joy, bliss.

Here's a quote from Jules Renard's *Journal* (May 1896) :

> - Voyage à Chitry.  — De la joie et de la tristesse selon que **le cœur** se serre ou **se dilate**, et il ne fait que ça.

Another quote from Flaubert in a letter to his lover, Louise Colet, from August 6 or 7 1846 :

> - Adieu, je ferme ma lettre.  C'est l'heure où, seul et pendant que tout dort, je tire le tiroir où sont mes trésors.  Je contemple tes pantoufles, le mouchoir, tes cheveux, le portrait, je relis tes lettres, j'en respire l'odeur musquée.  Si tu savais ce que je sens maintenant!… dans la nuit **mon cœur se dilate** et une rosée d'amour le pénètre.  Mille baisers, mille, partout, *partout*.

Comment: Désolé, mais je ne peux pas m'empêcher de penser à *la rate qui s'dilate*... ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre. La DeLorean est réparée!  Gaston Ouvrard, ça nous rajeunit pas!